# Using a gulp project on another machine

Tags: sass, gulp

I have gulp set up and working fine on one machine.
I have copied the directory to another machine which includes the package.json file that includes all the project dependencies.

Each time I run 'gulp' on the new machine it runs through the task but always finishes with

Error: Gem sass is not installed.

I have run sudo npm install to install dependencies from the the package.json and even tried to run npm install --save-dev gulp-ruby-sass

ANy ideas? thanks

Comment: Is the Sass gem installed?

Comment: Ah. beginners error, last machine had codekit so this stage wasn't necessary? installed sass gem and guess wha?t ;) thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like your project uses the ruby gem `sass`, which means you need to run the following on each machine:

`[sudo] gem install sass`

For a bit more info, SASS started as a ruby gem but [libSass](http://sass-lang.com/libsass) allows users to run SASS using other languages.